# How to write commands in a GDB script that get executed every time a particular brkpt is hit?

Tags: gdb

I need to debug a certain set of commands each time i invoke gdb - so I decided to put them in my .gdbinit. Everything was fine , till i decided to use `commands` (to execute a certain set of gdb commands each time a certain brkpt is hit). My script looks is as follows:

```
define setup
   handle SIGTRAP noprint nostop
   br 'Class1::Fun1(void)'
   run
   br 'Class2::Run(void)'
   c
   br Function2
   commands 3
     return 0 
     c
   end
end
```

Problem is , whenever I execute them one by one , it behaves perfectly , but when i source the script and run setup , it behaves weirdly after the commands (does not do what was previously doing).

Can anyone help ?

Comment: Could you specify what it is doing when it isn't doing what it should? For me setting up this function and running it works just like anticipated, i.e., it stops at the Class2::Run-function with a breakpoint setup at Function2 with commands attached to it.

Is the problem that you use "commands 3" and you can't assume that Function2 will be breakpoint number 3? You can them use "commands" without parameter to set commands to the last set breakpoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably not placing the commands on the breakpoint you think you are.

If I were you, I'd modify the script to the following:

```
define setup
   handle SIGTRAP noprint nostop
   br 'Class1::Fun1(void)'
   run
   br 'Class2::Run(void)'
   c
   br Function2
   commands
     return 0 
     c
   end
end
```

If no breakpoint target is given, `commands` associates with the most recent breakpoint.  This way, no matter what other breakpoints you have in your gdb session, your commands will be associated with the breakpoint at Function2.